# Intro to Java Programming book page 276. Selection Sort Array example

Tags: java

I am a beginner to Java and I am currently reading a book called Introduction to Java Programming. On page 276 there is an example for a Selection sort on a Array. I have sat here trying to work it out for hours and I just don't understand it.I understand this code is sorting the array in ascending order but I would be grateful if someone could explain in more detail what different parts of the code are doing exactly.

```
    double[] list = { 1, 9, 4.5, 6.6, 5.7, -4.5 };
    SelectionSort.selectionSort(list);

    public class SelectionSort {

        public static void selectionSort(double[] list) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {

                double currentMin = list[i];
                int currentMinIndex = i;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
                    if (currentMin > list[j]) {
                        currentMin = list[j];
                        currentMinIndex = j;

                    }
                }

                if (currentMinIndex != i) {
                    list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
                    list[i] = currentMin;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't just downvote, try to explain.

Comment: check out wikipedia's article on [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) it should clear up how it works

Comment: This question seems way too broad to me.

Comment: lookup 'selection sort' and compare it to this algorithm

Comment: Try this guy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nDMgr0-Yyo

Comment: and if wikipedia doesnt help, try this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns4TPTC8whw :-)

Comment: Another way is to make Dry Run with pen and paper.

Comment: Selection Sort is one of several naïve approaches to sorting---I remember inventing it on my own in highschool. Other naïve examples are bubble sort and insertion sort.

Comment: @JohnW - the reason this was closed is that it is a somewhat rhetorical question. You have functioning code, and it's a very simple code at that. By either adding some `System.out.println()` statements or walking through the logic with pencil and paper you will have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

The [Wikipedia entry for selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) might be what you're looking for. The code has comments explaining the process. Essentially, Selection sort iterates through the array and keeps track of the smallest value. If a new value is found that is smaller than the smallest value found prior to it, the two values are swapped.

```
/* a[0] to a[n-1] is the array to sort */
int i,j;
int iMin;

/* advance the position through the entire array */
/*   (could do j < n-1 because single element is also min element) */
for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
    /* find the min element in the unsorted a[j .. n-1] */

    /* assume the min is the first element */
    iMin = j;
    /* test against elements after j to find the smallest */
    for ( i = j+1; i < n; i++) {
        /* if this element is less, then it is the new minimum */  
        if (a[i] < a[iMin]) {
            /* found new minimum; remember its index */
            iMin = i;
        }
    }

    /* iMin is the index of the minimum element. Swap it with the current position */
    if ( iMin != j ) {
        swap(a[j], a[iMin]);
    }
}
```

Comment: man, you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

It's Selection Sort algorithm. It finds minimum number and puts it in top, if found smaller num, puts that one in top, it keeps doing it until entire list is sorted from minimum to maximum. Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort